# Vim autocmd based on file contents

Tags: latex, vim, sage, autocmd

I'm trying to set up Vim to detect when a .tex file contains the command '\usepackage{sagemath}', and run a command accordingly. I've gotten to

```
:au BufReadPost,BufWritePost *.tex TTarget sagepdf
```

but that will fire for all .tex files, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres an example in my filetype.vim on how to destinguish html types. You can easily modify to suit your logic. Note the getline(n) =~ lines

```
" HTML (.shtml and .stm for server side)
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html,*.htm,*.shtml,*.stm  call s:FThtml()

" Distinguish between HTML, XHTML and Django
fun! s:FThtml()
  let n = 1
  while n < 10 && n < line("$")
    if getline(n) =~ '\<DTD\s\+XHTML\s'
      setf xhtml
      return
    endif
    if getline(n) =~ '{%\s*\(extends\|block\)\>'
      setf html.django_template
"      setf htmldjango
      return
    endif
    let n = n + 1
  endwhile
  setf html
endfun
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should consider using a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline).

If you can't get what you want with a modeline, you can use your own function in `autocmd`, like this:

```
function! MyFunction()
  ...
endfunction

autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost *.tex call MyFunction()
```

and you probably can write a function that checks whether a certain pattern matches, and then runs whatever you want.